# When to create a navigation property in model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity

As a new programmer I am trying to understand when I should create navigation properties for my Models. What are the trade offs?

On the extremes, the model can just contain ever field need, or the base model can have navigation properties for every field?

Or should navigation property only be used for complex related entities (an entity with more than one property)?

Another consideration I am considering is what works best for MVC drop down or jquery autocomplete. How will designing the model impact application and sql performance?

```
public class Vendor 
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Number { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string PostalCode { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
}
```

or I could do this and assume the related tables also exists in the namespace and in turn the database.

```
public class Vendor 
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public virtual Name Name { get; set; }
    public virtual Number Number  { get; set; }
    public virtual Street Street { get; set; }
    public virtual City City { get; set; }
    public virtual State State { get; set; }
    public virtual PostalCode PostalCode { get; set; }
    public virtual Country Country { get; set; }
}
```

I can see that some of the related entities will be static in nature like States but Number and Street will grow over time.

Comment: I think you might be misunderstanding navigation properties [Relationships and Navigation Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/data/jj713564.aspx). The first model is fine, but the second makes no sense since `Name`, `Number` etc and not complex objects and do not have related tables in the database.  You might however have class `Address` which contains address properties and then `Vendor` would have `int ID`, `string Name` and `int AddressID`, `virtual Address Address`

Comment: Stephen, I was assuming that the related tables/properties exist in the namespace/database. I left them out to keep the question short.

Comment: Since say property `Number` is a string or int, why would you have a separate table for `Numbers`? A separate `Addresses` table may may sense if you  had possible multiple addresses for a vendor.

Answer (score 0):

If your property can be represented by a simple database column, then you use the first approach, if you property itself has its own properties, then you will need a navigational property. If your case, if the City also has properties such as Id, Name, etc, then you will use the navigation property, however, if you only want to store city as the name, your first approach will work.